# jsp form is not reaching javascript in eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, jsp

I'm trying form validation in jsp using Javascript.
My code looks like below. My jsp page is not reaching the .js file for validation in eclipse.

```js
function validateForm(){
 alert("entered js");
 
 var name = document.getElementsByName("name");
 var age = document.getElementsByName("age");
 var id = document.getElementsByName("id");
 
 //not null validation
 
 if(name == null || name == ""  ){
  alert("Please give your name");
 }
 
 if(age == null || age == ""){
  alert("Please give your age");
 }
 
 if(id == null || id == ""){
  alert("Pls give an id");
  
 }
 
 //age validation .. only numbers
 
 if(/\D/.test(age)){
  alert("Only numbers in age pls");
 }
 
 //id validation .. only numbers
 if(/\D/.test(id)){
  alert("only numbers in ID pls ..");
 }
 
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "/js/studentScript.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/HelloWeb/controller" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">

 <table>
 
  <tr>
   <td><label>Name: </label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td><label>Age: </label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="age"></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td><label>Id: </label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
  </tr>
 
 </table>
 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My project explorer looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgjIR.jpg)

Please suggest a solution

Comment: Should you have the first slash in the js URL (/js/studentScript.js)? Are you not missing the app root name?

Comment: If I am not wrong .. The whole WebContent folder gets loaded into Tomcat so I don't think removing the '/' will do much good .. also adding the root folder name does not help.. I tried both your suggestions.

Comment: Did you look at your browser console to see if there were any errors?

Comment: Which is your jsp location and what is location of js file???

Comment: Adding the root folder name, or the name of the module it is set to deploy as?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create a project with the same structure and files as yours 
to make the page worked i can suggest to try one of the following :

1- remove the slash at the beginning

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/studentScript.js"></script>
```

2-add the context name

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/studentScript.js"></script>
```

**both worked for me with no issues.**

Comment: Hi, you are right it does work normally with an html/jsp page.. But it doesnt work when Im trying to integrate this with Spring MVC.. Hence the issue. Please suggest some server side validation methods that work with Spring mvc ..

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem now .. The issue is im trying to apply Spring mvc in my project which does not allow client side validation using JScript (not in a usual way.. im still trying to research this subject). Hence the following issue.

Sorry if i troubled you guys.

Answer (score 0):

- Why js isn't responding?

  > The path to `.js` is not correct. Try using absolute url like `http[s]://host[:port]/HelloWeb/js/studentScript.js`
- There is error(not syntax error) the way js is written.

  > `document.getElementsByName()` gives you `NodeList` and not a single html element. To get the actual value from text boxes, use `value` attribute e.g. `document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value`, and so on for the rest.